# Local hostnames giving 'Temporary failure in name resolution' error

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, dns

I setup a brand new VM on my network with Ubuntu 22.04 and a static IP. However, for some reason I can't lookup machines on the local network via hostname. It works fine on my older VMS. Is there some step I am missing in my network setup?
netplan config.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 10.10.10.99/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.10.10.1
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.10.10.1
  version: 2
```

ping newserver

```
ping: newserver: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

nslookup newserver

```
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find newserver: SERVFAIL
```

resolvectl status

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (ens160)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 10.10.10.1
       DNS Servers: 10.10.10.1
```

The only thing I have done outside of the initial Ubuntu setup is install avahi-daemon and cif-utils.

Comment: Avahi shouldn't matter unless the name ends in `.local`. As a workaround, you can try hardcoding the names in `/etc/hosts`. Another bad workaround is disabling systemd-resolved and the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink, and hardcoding the `10.10.10.1` nameserver there

Comment: You can try a specific nameserver like this: `dig google.com @8.8.8.8` or `host google.com 8.8.8.8` change the 8.8.8.8 bit to whatever nameserver you think is most likely to work for you

Comment: Disabling systemd-resolved and hardcoding the name server in resolv.conf(after removing the symlink) didn't help.

Get 'Name or service not known' on ping, and 'server can;t find newserver: NXDOMAIN' on nslookup

Comment: If you want to use dig, use `dig newserver @10.10.10.1`

Comment: So `dig newserver @10.10.10.1` seems to give the correct response where `dig newserver` gets a SERVFAIL status. Not sure how this leads to a fix though.

Comment: Please [edit] with `resolvectl status`

Comment: What if you hardcode the DNS in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and restart? Please also [edit] with `sudo resolvectl log-level debug; resolvectl query newserver` and then look for relevant lines in `journalctl -r -u systemd-resolved`

Comment: hardcoding DNS in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf did not make a difference.

Comment: resolvectl query newserver
`newserver: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found`

Comment: Have you tried setting `Domains=~.`?

Comment: No luck with `Domains=~.`